# Sequelize MySQL Model extended as class findOrCreate method fails to create record

Tags: node.js, discord.js, sequelize.js

My issue would be that when the below code runs, it builds the MySQL query and runs it, however, it throws this error: `ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: Guilds.GuildPremium cannot be null`.

However, these fields have default values defined in the super init method in the Model. What is the purpose of defining default values in the Model, if the instance of said Model is not inheriting the properties of the Model? 
Also, do I have to define default values again in the code snippet below?

Thank you for your patience and time :)

The code snippet that ran:

```
const {NewGuild, created} = Guilds.findOrCreate({
    where: {
        DiscordGuildID: Guild.id
    }
})
    .then(() => {
        if(created) {
            console.log(`Guild ${Guild.id} added to Database!`);
        }
            else {
                NewGuild
                    .update({
                        GuildActive: true
                    })
                    .then(() => 
                        console.log(`Guild ${Guild.id} reactivated in Database!`)
                    );
            };
    });
```

Model Guilds:

```
module.exports = class Guilds extends Model {
static init(sequelize) {
    return super.init({
        GuildID: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            comment: "Guild Database ID"
        },
        DiscordGuildID: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false
        },
        GuildPremium: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            default: false
        },
        DiscordGuildPrefix: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            default: process.env.DefaultPrefix
        },
        GuildActive: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            default: true,
            comment: "Bot active in Guild?"
        }
    }, {
        tableName: "Guilds",
        modelName: "Guilds",
        timestamps: true,
        sequelize
    });
};
```

Legend:

- Guilds = class Guilds extends Model
- Guild = instance of class Discord.Guild

Log of the event:

```
 
    2021-11-21T15:01:05.998950+00:00 app[worker.1]: Executing (): SELECT `GuildID`, `DiscordGuildID`, `GuildPremium`, `DiscordGuildPrefix`, `GuildActive`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Guilds` AS `Guilds` WHERE `Guilds`.`DiscordGuildID` = '728450482284134461' LIMIT 1;   
errors: [
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039336+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ValidationErrorItem {
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039336+00:00 app[worker.1]:       message: 'Guilds.GuildPremium cannot be null',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039337+00:00 app[worker.1]:       type: 'notNull Violation',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039337+00:00 app[worker.1]:       path: 'GuildPremium',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039337+00:00 app[worker.1]:       value: null,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039337+00:00 app[worker.1]:       origin: 'CORE',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039337+00:00 app[worker.1]:       instance: Guilds {
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039337+00:00 app[worker.1]:         dataValues: {
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039338+00:00 app[worker.1]:           GuildID: null,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039338+00:00 app[worker.1]:           DiscordGuildID: '728450482284134461',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039338+00:00 app[worker.1]:           updatedAt: 2021-11-21T15:01:06.017Z,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039338+00:00 app[worker.1]:           createdAt: 2021-11-21T15:01:06.017Z
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039339+00:00 app[worker.1]:         },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039339+00:00 app[worker.1]:         _previousDataValues: { DiscordGuildID: undefined },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039339+00:00 app[worker.1]:         _changed: Set(1) { 'DiscordGuildID' },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039340+00:00 app[worker.1]:         _options: {
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039340+00:00 app[worker.1]:           isNewRecord: true,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039340+00:00 app[worker.1]:           _schema: null,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039340+00:00 app[worker.1]:           _schemaDelimiter: '',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039341+00:00 app[worker.1]:           attributes: undefined,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039341+00:00 app[worker.1]:           include: undefined,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039341+00:00 app[worker.1]:           raw: undefined,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039341+00:00 app[worker.1]:           silent: undefined
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039341+00:00 app[worker.1]:         },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039341+00:00 app[worker.1]:         isNewRecord: true
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039342+00:00 app[worker.1]:       },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039342+00:00 app[worker.1]:       validatorKey: 'is_null',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039342+00:00 app[worker.1]:       validatorName: null,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039342+00:00 app[worker.1]:       validatorArgs: []
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039342+00:00 app[worker.1]:     },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039342+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ValidationErrorItem {
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039342+00:00 app[worker.1]:       message: 'Guilds.DiscordGuildPrefix cannot be null',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039343+00:00 app[worker.1]:       type: 'notNull Violation',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039343+00:00 app[worker.1]:       path: 'DiscordGuildPrefix',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039343+00:00 app[worker.1]:       value: null,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039343+00:00 app[worker.1]:       origin: 'CORE',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039343+00:00 app[worker.1]:       instance: Guilds {
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039343+00:00 app[worker.1]:         dataValues: {
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039344+00:00 app[worker.1]:           GuildID: null,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039344+00:00 app[worker.1]:           DiscordGuildID: '728450482284134461',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039344+00:00 app[worker.1]:           updatedAt: 2021-11-21T15:01:06.017Z,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039344+00:00 app[worker.1]:           createdAt: 2021-11-21T15:01:06.017Z
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039344+00:00 app[worker.1]:         },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039344+00:00 app[worker.1]:         _previousDataValues: { DiscordGuildID: undefined },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039344+00:00 app[worker.1]:         _changed: Set(1) { 'DiscordGuildID' },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039345+00:00 app[worker.1]:         _options: {
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039345+00:00 app[worker.1]:           isNewRecord: true,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039345+00:00 app[worker.1]:           _schema: null,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039345+00:00 app[worker.1]:           _schemaDelimiter: '',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039345+00:00 app[worker.1]:           attributes: undefined,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039345+00:00 app[worker.1]:           include: undefined,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039345+00:00 app[worker.1]:           raw: undefined,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039345+00:00 app[worker.1]:           silent: undefined
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039346+00:00 app[worker.1]:         },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039347+00:00 app[worker.1]:         isNewRecord: true
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039347+00:00 app[worker.1]:       },
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039347+00:00 app[worker.1]:       validatorKey: 'is_null',
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039347+00:00 app[worker.1]:       validatorName: null,
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039348+00:00 app[worker.1]:       validatorArgs: []
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039348+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
    2021-11-21T15:01:06.039348+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default values don't work in your code because you indicated incorrect option for that. Replace `default` with `defaultValue` and it does the trick:

```js
GuildPremium: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: false
        },
DiscordGuildPrefix: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: process.env.DefaultPrefix
        },
        GuildActive: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: true,
            comment: "Bot active in Guild?"
        }
```

See [Default values](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#default-values) in the official documentation.

Comment: Oh yeah, I always conflate the 2. Thank you :)